# The ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead

Tags: audio

There is a sound recorder and a recorded sound player on the site. It's fine with Firefox, but I get the following warning in Chronium-based browsers.

> [Deprecation] The ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead. (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet)

```
this.config = {
                        bufferLen: 4096,
                        numChannels: 2,
                        mimeType: 'audio/ogg'
                    };
                    this.recording = false;
                    this.callbacks = {
                        getBuffer: [],
                        exportWAV: []
                    };
                    Object.assign(this.config, cfg);
                    this.context = source.context;
                    this.node = (this.context.createScriptProcessor || this.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(this.context, this.config.bufferLen, this.config.numChannels, this.config.numChannels);
                    this.node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
                        if (!_this.recording) return;
                        var buffer = [];
                        for (var channel = 0; channel < _this.config.numChannels; channel++) {
                            buffer.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel));
                        }
                        _this.worker.postMessage({
                            command: 'record',
                            buffer: buffer
                        });
                    };
```

[Full Code on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/E4t09Q6W)

[image]

How can I make this change?

Comment: This blog explains how to replace. Was very useful for me
[link](https://itguytec.com/2022/07/24/replace-scriptprocessornode)

Answer (score 5):

The ScriptProcessorNode has been "deprecated" for years, but it isn't going anywhere anytime soon.

However, you don't need it anyway if you want a Vorbis or Opus audio recording in Ogg.  Use the MediaRecorder API instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder

Answer (score 0):

The great example how to work with MediaRecorder you can find there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder#example
I have redevelop my source to us this example. Who know when ScriptProcessorNode will be removed.

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
  console.log("getUserMedia supported.");

  const constraints = { audio: true };
  let chunks = [];

  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

      record.onclick = () => {
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        console.log("recorder started");
        record.style.background = "red";
        record.style.color = "black";
      };

      stop.onclick = () => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        console.log("recorder stopped");
        record.style.background = "";
        record.style.color = "";
      };

      mediaRecorder.onstop = (e) => {
        console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

        const clipName = prompt("Enter a name for your sound clip");

        const clipContainer = document.createElement("article");
        const clipLabel = document.createElement("p");
        const audio = document.createElement("audio");
        const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

        clipContainer.classList.add("clip");
        audio.setAttribute("controls", "");
        deleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
        clipLabel.textContent = clipName;

        clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
        clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
        clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
        soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

        audio.controls = true;
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
        chunks = [];
        const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        audio.src = audioURL;
        console.log("recorder stopped");

        deleteButton.onclick = (e) => {
          const evtTgt = e.target;
          evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
        };
      };

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
        chunks.push(e.data);
      };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`The following error occurred: ${err}`);
    });
}
```